# How to properly connect to XAMPP mySQL DB using context.xml

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, context.xml, dbconnection

I'm setting up a connection with XAMPP MySQL DB using context.xml. Where do I shall put my schema (database) name, username, password? I'm trying to this like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Context path="/ParkingSystem">
    <Resource 
        name="jdbc/ParkingBookSystem" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxTotal="20"
        maxIdle="5"
        maxWaitMillis="10000"
        username="root"
        password=""
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    />
</Context>
```

But getting no connection? :( Where do I make mistake? My schem,a name in phpMyAdmin is: test. My DB name: rezerwacje_miejsc. Rest is deafult for XAMPP mySQL 0 I did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, there is nothing wrong with the code. I used to change the default password on localhost to another and forgot about it. The case can be closed.